# Why is File.Move not working as expected?

Tags: c#

I am trying to move all files from `rootFolderPath` to `destinationPath`

```
try
{
    string rootFolderPath = @"D:\Log_siteq\";
    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(@"D:\Log_takaya\" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(@"D:\Log_takaya\" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()));
    }


    string destinationPath = Path.Combine(@"D:\Log_takaya\" + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() );
    string fileTypes = @"*.*";
    string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(rootFolderPath, fileTypes);
    foreach (string file in fileList)
    {
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(file);
        string destination = Path.Combine(destinationPath,file);                 
        File.Move( file,destination);
        MessageBox.Show(file);
        MessageBox.Show(destination);
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Apparently `MessageBox.Show(file);` shows me my root folder path ( as is normal) but `MessageBox.Show(destination);` is showing me the same thing.

What gives? It just moves my `file` from my root folder in the same folder.Am I not getting something?

Comment: Don't use Path.Combine like this. Don't use + to combine paths. Use like this: Path.Combine("D:\Log_takaya", comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() );

Comment: Didn't see that,slipped me.But the problem remains ,nothing changed.

Answer (score 7):

You are combining the `destinationPath` with the complete file path of `file`:

```
string destination = Path.Combine(destinationPath, file);
```

which will just overwrite the destination with the original file path (because "C:\desitnation\C:\source\filename.txt" isn't a valid path).

Instead, you need only the file name like this:

```
string destination = Path.Combine(destinationPath, Path.GetFileName(file));
```